# Как создать модульное android приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, модули

Например, приложение делится на три модуля: Core, Personal, Client; 
В Core определены основные библиотеки и методы которые будут переиспользовать остальные модули. Personal и Client - это модули со своим набором activity и бизнес логикой. При авторизации пользователя выбирается, какой модуль использовать. 
Подскажите, как разрешить зависимости между модулями, а так же каким образом может происходить выбор модуля в зависимости от триггера у пользователя?

Comment: Что вы под этим понимаете?  `При авторизации пользователя выбирается, какой модуль использовать. ` Разные окна или вкладки открыть?

Comment: В каждом модуле свой MainActivity , специфичный Drawer и своя логика использования приложения. Тоесть если логинится клиент компании, то используется один модуль, если логинится  кто то из персонала , то другой. А в модуле Core например находится активити авторизации и REST.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Создание модуля (библиотеки)

Для создания модуля в ***Android Studio*** выбираете

```
 File > New > New Module
```

Далее есть 2 варианта. Если вы планируете создать «чистую» java-библиотеку, в качестве типа указывайте ***Java Library***, в итоге код такой библиотеки скомпилируется в *JAR* файл. Это удобно, так как вы сможете использовать ее не только в Android приложениях. Если же вы собираетесь использовать android-специфичные вещи и вам понадобятся классы из пакетов `android.*`, то создавайте ***Android Library***, которая при компиляции собирается в *AAR* файл. В данном случае вам понядобится последний вариант.

**ВАЖНО:** В `minSDKVersion` (файлы build.gradle модулей) приложения должен совпадать или быть больше, чем указанный в модуле библиотеки.Указанные `buildToolsVersion` должны быть установлены в Android-SDK. Каждый модуль библиотеки генерирует свой класс ресурсов (*.R.class). Когда Android библиотеки добавляются в проект и происходит его сборка, то их ресурсы сливаются, что может привести к конфликтам. Поэтому в документации определены следующие соглашения:

- Если ID ресурса приложения совпадает с ID ресурса в библиотеке, то используется ресурс приложения
- Если ID ресурса совпадает в разных библиотеках, то используется ресурс библиотеки, которая указана первой в списке зависимостей (находится выше в блоке `dependecies`)
- Для избежания описанных выше конфликтов рекомендуется использовать префикс или другую последовательную схему именования ресурсов, которая будет уникальна для каждого из модулей (или уникальна для всего приложения вцелом)

### Подключение Android библиотеки

Подключаются Android библиотеки как зависимости (если библиотека была создана  как отдельный проект в AndroidStudio).
Тут есть так же 2 варианта:

1.Либо добавить скомпилированный AAR (или JAR) файл:

```
- File > New Module 

- Import .JAR/.AAR Package > Next

- вводите путь до ARR (или JAR) файла > Finish
```

2.Либо импортировать библиотеку из исходников:

```
- File > New > Import Module 

- вводите путь до директории, в которой находятся исходники библиотеки > Finish
```

**ВАЖНО:** убедиться, что имя Android библиотеки было добавлено в *settings.gradle*

```
include ':app', ':core', ':personal', ':client'
```

и появилась в блоке `dependencies` файла *build.gradle* приложения

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile project(":personal")
    compile project(":client")
}
```

Android библиотеки могут содержать в себе ресурсы, другие JAR  библиотеки, собственный *AndroidManifest.xml*.

### Структура скомпилированной Android библиотеки

Скомпилированная Android библиотека представляет собой обычный `zip` архив с расширением `.arr`, который содержит следующие обязательные файлы и директории:

- /AndroidManifest.xml
- /classes.jar
- /res/
- /R.txt

и необязательные:

- /assets/
- /libs/*name*.jar
- /jni/*abi_name*/*name*.so (где *abi_name* один из поддерживаемых [Android ABIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa))
- /proguard.txt
- /lint.jar

Comment: А как это сделать без студии и градла?

Comment: @bukkojot смотря что вы хотите? вы хотите заинжектить свой модуль в готовое приложение? или просто пишите все в блокнотике? уточните, что вы хотите и я вам расскажу как =)

Comment: Пишу в блокнотике. Точнее, пытаюсь писать в блокнотике. Точнее, раньше я мог писать в блокнотике, паковать ассеты в aapt, в нем же генерил айдишники для ресурсов, затем компилял все через javac+dx, подписывал через jarsigner и выравнивал zipalign. За последние года 3 что-то изменилось, появились AAR-пакеты, aapt используется только для обработки картинок, javac+dx вообще больше не используются, а процесс сборки простого хелловорлда через Градл вполне может выжрать пару гигов оперативы. И как жить дальше я представляю достаточно слабо, особенно если у тебя не так много оперативы и все тормозит.

Comment: @bukkojot я вас понял, тогда задавайте вопрос... и я вечером на него отвечу - думаю просто многим будет полезно понимание как это собрать без привязке к AndroidStudio или Eclipse  и тд.

Comment: Без Градла, это главное. Попробую сформулировать вопрос чуть позже, если это никто не сделает раньше.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687556/Как-собрать-произвольное-приложение-под-android-без-использовани-gradle-ant-andr